# Constrained optimization with max and absolute values in objective function

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I would like to find the optimal set $ \{ x_i \} $ given $ L $ and $ \{ a_i \} $ that minimizes the problem below.  My first thought was to use linear programming.  Is there a transformation that makes it possible, or do I need a more general optimization technique?

$$ \min_{x_i} \left[ 2\sum_i | x_i |  + \max_i | x_i + a_i | \right]$$
$$ \mathrm{s.t.} \sum_i (x_i + a_i) \le L$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't told us what set $i$ ranges over, so I'll just assume $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$.

A standard trick in LP formulation of problems with absolute values is to introduce auxiliary variables and constraints with the basic idea that

$\min | x | $

is equivalent to

$\min t $

$t \geq x $

$t \geq -x $

Applying that idea to your problem, introduce auxiliary variables $t_{i}$, $i=1, 2, \ldots n$, and $s$.  Then formulate the problem as:

$\min 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} t_{i}    +  s $

subject to

$t_{i} \geq x_{i}$, $i=1, 2, \ldots n$.

$t_{i} \geq -x_{i}$, $i=1, 2, \ldots n$.

$s \geq x_{i}+a_{i} $, $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$.

$s \geq -(x_{i}+a_{i}) $, $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$.

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{i}+a_{i}) \leq L$

Comment: Thanks, but what happened to the $\max$?

Comment: $s$ is larger than any of the $x_i+a_i$ and $-(x_i+a_i)$, so it is larger than their max. What Brian has shown you is a standard trick to convert a problem like yours into a linear problem with linear constraints -- the sort of problem for which there are many standard implementations.

Comment: As Wolfgang explained, $s$ will be greater than or equal to $ | x_{i}+a_{i} | $ for $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$.  Also, since $s$ is being minimized in the objective, it will come out equal to the maximum of the absolute values of $x_{i}+a_{i}$.